# How to sum values if the number of rows exceeds the desired number in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Example of mydata

```
mydata=structure(list(sales_point_id = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), calendar_id_operday = 1:53, 
    line_fact_amt = c(2026319.95, 2509383.87, 2859932.59, 2652536.9, 
    2144475.76, 2844606.9, 3293532.23, 2383631.93, 3053991.07, 
    2591633.34, 2720567.16, 1764697.43, 1128645.17, 1323423.8, 
    1502345.65, 1612565.65, 1313644.68, 1233464.32, 1211636.57, 
    2061583.23, 1090641.31, 1428333.73, 1474186.08, 1607467.17, 
    1180338.86, 1307456.84, 1047247.48, 1657799.59, 1515859.51, 
    2682571.39, 1350357.67, 1513109.28, 1549993.26, 1812758.27, 
    1437857.75, 1620922.46, 2066836.55, 1248856.87, 1107869.92, 
    2884296.49, 1766246.4, 1496881.03, 1166676.17, 1376484.9, 
    1188265.97, 1985668.28, 1094000.85, 1352298.36, 1616352.89, 
    1856824.59, 1726768.06, 1823672, 972326.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L))
```

As we can see `sales_point_id` has 53 rows. How to do that if for each `sales_point_id` (this is group variable)count of rows >52, then for variable `line_fact_amt` sum the values of the rows that come after line 52.
In this example

```
sales_point_id  calendar_id_operday line_fact_amt
2               52                  1823672
2               53                  972326,75
```

sum `line_fact_amt` `for 52 and  53 1823672+972326,75=2795998,75`, so this value will be put for 52 rows of `calendar_id_operday`.

So Desired output

```
sales_point_id  calendar_id_operday line_fact_amt
2   1   2026319.95
2   2   2509383.87
2   3   2859932.59
2   4   2652536.9
2   5   2144475.76
2   6   2844606.9
2   7   3293532.23
2   8   2383631.93
2   9   3053991.07
2   10  2591633.34
2   11  2720567.16
2   12  1764697.43
2   13  1128645.17
2   14  1323423.8
2   15  1502345.65
2   16  1612565.65
2   17  1313644.68
2   18  1233464.32
2   19  1211636.57
2   20  2061583.23
2   21  1090641.31
2   22  1428333.73
2   23  1474186.08
2   24  1607467.17
2   25  1180338.86
2   26  1307456.84
2   27  1047247.48
2   28  1657799.59
2   29  1515859.51
2   30  2682571.39
2   31  1350357.67
2   32  1513109.28
2   33  1549993.26
2   34  1812758.27
2   35  1437857.75
2   36  1620922.46
2   37  2066836.55
2   38  1248856.87
2   39  1107869.92
2   40  2884296.49
2   41  1766246.4
2   42  1496881.03
2   43  1166676.17
2   44  1376484.9
2   45  1188265.97
2   46  1985668.28
2   47  1094000.85
2   48  1352298.36
2   49  1616352.89
2   50  1856824.59
2   51  1726768.06
2   52  2795998,75
```

for each `sales_point_id` by all variables must be 52 rows.
How to do it?
Thank you advance.

Comment: Do you always have at least 52 rows of data  per id?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will replace `line_fact_amt` in *all* rows starting from 52 with their sum.

```r
g <- seq.int(nrow(mydata))
i <- as.logical(g %/% 52)
mydata[i, "line_fact_amt"] <- sum(mydata[i, "line_fact_amt"])
tail(mydata)
#>    sales_point_id calendar_id_operday line_fact_amt
#> 48              2                  48       1352298
#> 49              2                  49       1616353
#> 50              2                  50       1856825
#> 51              2                  51       1726768
#> 52              2                  52       2795999
#> 53              2                  53       2795999
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In order to keep only the first 52 rows, do

```
head(mydata, 52)
```

---

## Edit

A function based on the code above can be used to compute the wanted  results by group of `sales_point_id`.

### 1. Base R

```r
sumFun52 <- function(data){
  g <- seq.int(nrow(data))
  i <- as.logical(g %/% 52)
  data[i, "line_fact_amt"] <- sum(data[i, "line_fact_amt"])
  head(data, 52)
}

sp <- split(mydata, mydata$sales_point_id)
res <- lapply(sp, sumFun52)
do.call(rbind, res)
#>      sales_point_id calendar_id_operday line_fact_amt
#> 2.1               2                   1       2026320
#> 2.2               2                   2       2509384
#> 2.3               2                   3       2859933
#> 2.4               2                   4       2652537
#> 2.5               2                   5       2144476
#> 2.6               2                   6       2844607
#> 2.7               2                   7       3293532
#> 2.8               2                   8       2383632
#> 2.9               2                   9       3053991
#> 2.10              2                  10       2591633
#> 2.11              2                  11       2720567
#> 2.12              2                  12       1764697
#> 2.13              2                  13       1128645
#> 2.14              2                  14       1323424
#> 2.15              2                  15       1502346
#> 2.16              2                  16       1612566
#> 2.17              2                  17       1313645
#> 2.18              2                  18       1233464
#> 2.19              2                  19       1211637
#> 2.20              2                  20       2061583
#> 2.21              2                  21       1090641
#> 2.22              2                  22       1428334
#> 2.23              2                  23       1474186
#> 2.24              2                  24       1607467
#> 2.25              2                  25       1180339
#> 2.26              2                  26       1307457
#> 2.27              2                  27       1047247
#> 2.28              2                  28       1657800
#> 2.29              2                  29       1515860
#> 2.30              2                  30       2682571
#> 2.31              2                  31       1350358
#> 2.32              2                  32       1513109
#> 2.33              2                  33       1549993
#> 2.34              2                  34       1812758
#> 2.35              2                  35       1437858
#> 2.36              2                  36       1620922
#> 2.37              2                  37       2066837
#> 2.38              2                  38       1248857
#> 2.39              2                  39       1107870
#> 2.40              2                  40       2884296
#> 2.41              2                  41       1766246
#> 2.42              2                  42       1496881
#> 2.43              2                  43       1166676
#> 2.44              2                  44       1376485
#> 2.45              2                  45       1188266
#> 2.46              2                  46       1985668
#> 2.47              2                  47       1094001
#> 2.48              2                  48       1352298
#> 2.49              2                  49       1616353
#> 2.50              2                  50       1856825
#> 2.51              2                  51       1726768
#> 2.52              2                  52       2795999
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 2. `tidyverse`

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(purrr)

mydata %>%
  group_split(sales_point_id) %>%
  map_dfr(sumFun52)
#> # A tibble: 52 x 3
#>    sales_point_id calendar_id_operday line_fact_amt
#>             <int>               <int>         <dbl>
#>  1              2                   1      2026320.
#>  2              2                   2      2509384.
#>  3              2                   3      2859933.
#>  4              2                   4      2652537.
#>  5              2                   5      2144476.
#>  6              2                   6      2844607.
#>  7              2                   7      3293532.
#>  8              2                   8      2383632.
#>  9              2                   9      3053991.
#> 10              2                  10      2591633.
#> # ... with 42 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`'s `n`, which gives the current group size, we can sum values based on index, and append that to the first 51 rows of data.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(sales_point_id) %>%
  summarise(
    calendar_id_operday = if(n() > 52) 1:52 else calendar_id_operday,
    line_fact_amt = if(n() > 52) {
      c(line_fact_amt[1:51], sum(line_fact_amt[52:n()]))
    } else {
      line_fact_amt
    },
    .groups = "drop",
  )
```